# Unit Testing ICommand with NSubstitute

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have the following ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : IMyViewModel
{
    private readonly IMyModel myMode;
    private ICommand _myCommand;

    public MyViewModel(IMyModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(x => MyMethod())); }
    }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        _model.SomeModelMethod();
    }
}
```

where IMyViewModel is defind as

```
public interface IMyViewModel
{
    ICommand MyCommand { get; }
}
```

and my interface for the model is defined as

```
public interface IMyModel
{
    void SomeOtherCommand();
}
```

Now in my unit test (using NSubstitute) I want to check that when MyCommand is invoked my model receives a call to its method `SomeModelMethod`. I've tried:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyViewModel_OnMyCommand_CallsSomeOtherMethodOnModel()
{
   var model = Substitute.For<IMyModel>();
   var viewModel = Substitute.For<IMyViewModel>();

   viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);

   model.Received().SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

but this doesn't currently work. How do I best test that my Model method is called when a command on my ViewModel is invoked?

Comment: Rather than creating a substiture for the viewModel, you're probably going to want to do `new viewModel(model.object)`, or whatever the substitute equivalent is.  You don't want to mock the object you're actually testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're mocking `IMyViewModel` here. You said you wanted to test whether  `SomeOtherMethod` is invoked when you execute the command in `MyViewModel`.

You shouldn't be mocking the `MyViewModel` here.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyViewModel_OnMyCommand_CallsSomeOtherMethodOnModel()
{
   var model = Substitute.For<IMyModel>();
   var viewModel = new MyViewModel(model);

   viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null);

   model.Received().SomeOtherMethod();
}
```

P.S: I'm not familiar with nsubstitute. But the idea is still same (you shouldn't mock MyViewModel). Make sure you're using the right methods in nsubstitute.

Comment: Thanks, but Visual Studio is now shouting that is expects a Method, Delegate or Event when trying to invoke `viewModel.MyCommand(null)`. I'm still unclear as how to properly invoke the ICommand. Any suggestions?

Comment: D'oh. It should read `viewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null)` Thanks

Comment: @JamesB Ha, I copied your code and made the same typo :) Glad that you solved it.